# How to make Tomcat 7 prompt for a client certificate

Tags: tomcat, client-certificates

I have a Tomcat 7.0.62 installation and I want it to prompt for a client certificate on users connection. I am using native library and APR and this is the connector that I am using:

```
<Connector SSLCertificateFile="Y:\server.pem" SSLCertificateKeyFile="Y:\server.pem" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="true" maxThreads="32" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true"/>
```

As far as I know, that would be enough. The clientAuth option should make the browser ask the user for a certificate. However, when I access to https://localhost:8443 nothing happens. I have double-checked I have valid certificates in my certificate store.

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry. I misread the documentation. The HTTPS APR connector attribute to ask the client for a certificate is SSLVerifyClient as you can read in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_APR/Native.

```
<Connector port="9443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="5" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLVerifyClient="optionalNoCA" sslProtocol="TLSv1" SSLEngine="on"
           SSLCertificateFile="C:\localhost-rsa-cert.pem" 
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:localhost-rsa-key.pem" />
```

Comment: Hi @ChristopherSchultz,
I do apologize, I did not realize the link I provided was for Tomcat 5. I have edited my answer to fix the mistake. Now the link points to the Tomcat 7 documentation.
Thank you for pointing my mistake out.
Regards,